# Cannot create a Qt dialog inside another

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

This code generates two separate dialogs, while I would like one to be inside the other:

```
   class MyTree : public QWidget {
        QTreeView *view;
        ...
   }
   //class MyTree : public QDialog {...}   // same result

   QApplication testApp(argc, argv);
   QDialog *topWidget = new QDialog;
   MyTree *pjrTree = MyTree::Build();
   pjrTree->setParent(topWidget);
   topWidget->show();
   testApp.exec();
```

Both the dialog and the tree appear correctly. I just cannot enforce the containment relation.

Comment: I believe you want `dialog->setModal(false)` - not that that is a good idea, rather make a more powerfull (designed) dialog that extends if ( condition )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deriving the class MyTree from `QTreeView`, instead of having a pointer to `QTreeView` as a member variable, fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it completely incorrectly. You have to create a layout, which contains your elements.

Look at this example:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/dialogs-findfiles.html

Answer (score 0):

Your solution set only parent of `pjrTree` but don't add it to QDialog layout. You can simply inherent `class MyTree` from `QDialog`, which directly inherent `QWidget`. It would be more clear and correct.

Comment: MyTree now derives from QDialog. Same result.

Comment: are you still using `topWidget` ? now it should be done without